# How to call an async method inside a manually created task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I need to implement something like a cold observable object in RxJS (just a standard Observable). I need to call an async method inside a task I create myself via constructor (new Task()). I need to implement this because before executing any asynchronous code I want to do some stuff which is very specific to my project. So I want to recieve a task that is not started yet which I can start manually a little bit later.

So far I came to the following decision and to my surprise it isn't working!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = CallApi(() => t.Go());
        var task2 =  CallApi2(() => t.Go());


        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();

    }



    public static Task<T> CallApi<T>(Func<Task<T>> function)
    {
        if (function == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(function));
        }


        return new Task<Task<T>>(async () =>
        {
            return await function();
        }).Unwrap();


    }

    public static Task<T> CallApi2<T>(Func<Task<T>> function)
    {
        if (function == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(function));
        }

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        var resultTask = new Task<Task<T>>(() =>
        {
            var t = function();

            t.ContinueWith(
                task => {
                    tcs.SetResult(task.Result);
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
            );

            t.ContinueWith(
                task => {
                    tcs.SetCanceled();
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled
            );

            t.ContinueWith(
                task => {
                    tcs.SetException(task.Exception);

                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
            );
            return tcs.Task;
        });

        return resultTask.Unwrap();

    }
}
```

It seems that calling Unwrap or using TaskCompletionSource creates a task in a WaitingForActivation state. And calling Start method on tasks in this state leads me to the exception which is saying:

> Start may not be called on a promise-style task.

So it's very likely that .NET distinguishes special kind of tasks - promise-style tasks.

In summary my questions are:

1. What do these promise-style tasks mean?
2. How can I do what I want to do?

Comment: Unwrap does not do what you think it does. Your cold tasks can never be started, you lost the reference to them after the Unwrap() call. Think of the function is simply implemented as `public static async Task<T> Unwrap(this Task<Task<T>> task) { return await task; }` the internal `await task` will never complete because you lost any way to start that outer task.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I haven't been thinking about it in this way. That's why I tried to call Start on the task returned by Unwrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise style tasks are tasks that are not based on threads, they are based on events, For a `TaskCompletionSource` the "event" is the act of calling `SetResult`, `SetCanceled` or `SetException`

To receive a task that is not started yet which you can start manually a little bit later, simply hold on to the `Func<Task<T>>` and you evaluate the function to start up the task at the later point in time. This can be done quite simply.

```
    public void Example()
    {
        Func<Task<T>> func1 = () => t.Go();

        //Do other work

        Task<T> task1 = func1(); //t.Go() is not called until this point then the task starts.

    }
```

Comment: That's what I got with at the moment. I just used a delegate like in your example and surely it works. It starts a task when I call it. But I want to do exactly the same thing when using only tasks. Isn't it possible?

Comment: The cold tasks just are holding on to the delegate you pass in to the constructor then using up a extra thread to execute the delegate. There is no way to do this "without delegates" because that is the only thing the constructor to the task accepts. Save your self some performance by not using unnecessary threads and just run the delegate yourself.

Comment: You can see my tries to do it in my question. I just pass the delegate to the CallApi method which creates a "cold" task. But this cold task isn't starting at all. It throws the exception I told about. Can you provide me a way to do it irrespectively of the perfomance questions?

Comment: No, be cause I feel cold tasks are a inappropriate way to do and should not be worked with unless you are writing a custom thread scheduler, I am not gong to teach someone how to do something that I think is a bad way to do it. Just use delegates.

Comment: I agree with you. It will slow down the perfomance. But maybe it's not critical in someone's application. And for educational purposes it's gonna to be very useful to know how the way how to start such a task.

Comment: And I don't understand why .NET makes such a limitation. Why can't I call Start method? What is the problem with it? Async methods use TaskCompletionSource under the hood. And all the tasks are executed in another thread anyway. So how does "event based" stuff relate to it?

Comment: Lets say you are waiting for the mail to show up and deliver you a package so you can play a new game that you ordered on amazon. You call me on the phone and make a promise that *"once the mail shows up you are going to start playing your game"*. Later I come over and tell you "I need you to start to do your promise "start playing your game when the mail shows up"", how do you start doing that? You can't because the **task** you are going to do is a **promise** to do something once the **event** of the mail showing up happens, there is no way to "start" doing it, you wait on a outside source.

Comment: Does that analogy help explain it? You can't start a TaskCompletionSource because it is just a "promise" to set the task to `Completed` once someone calls one of the 3 functions  `SetResult`, `SetCanceled` or `SetException`. You can't "start" fulfilling that promise early because the promise is to set a variable once one of those 3 functions are called. Without the functions called there is nothing to "start", and when the functions are called they set the status of the Task during the call.

Comment: Yes. You're right. It is impossible to start doing an event if you have just a task retrieved through TaskCompletionSource. Because it is just a link between a real Task and a client. And I guess Unwrap uses the same TaskCompletionSource under the hood so it will return the same promise-style task. So I guess the answer to my question is - it is impossible to make it look like what I want it to be through using just Tasks and TaskCompletionSource. The nearest analog to the Observable in RxJS I can get is using Task<Task<TResult>> or just using the delegates (or some wrapper arround them).